# Start Cluster automatically at Glassfish 3.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, glassfish

I am able to start Glassfish domain automatically, in other words I can run it as a service by using "asadmin create-service". When machine is restarted, domain is getting up automcatically.

I want similar thing for all instances of a cluster of domain started. Since when machine is restarted domain is run automatically, but instances in this machine still keep down.

Is it possible to start the cluster automatically?

**Platform : Ubuntu 12.04**

**AS= Glassfish 3.1**

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the glassfish service script file under /etc/init.d/ by adding .

```
 asadmin start-domain   $DOMAIN >/dev/null 2>&1; $ASADMIN  start-cluster $CLUSTER >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```